# Tricky riddle from sister

Tags: pattern

This is a short riddle from my 12 year old sister.

**Can you solve it ?**

> $3 + 3 = 8$
>   $2 + 2 = Fish$
>   $0 + 0 = Glasses$
>   $1 + 1 = M$
>   $7 + 7 = ?$

Comment: Does your sister watch the Simpsons? S09E17 https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/e/e2/PuzzleAnswer.png/revision/latest?cb=20160827025950

Comment: Hahaha XD, so she got it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> LOVE. Take the first number and reverse it's glyph, and then fuse it with the other number to make a pictorial representation of the word. $7+7$ looks like a heart.

Comment: Correct! I thought of a triangle.